# Joining of two tables in IPython notebook

Tags: ipython, google-bigquery

I am trying to join table A with table B and I have diabled legacy sql in google big query and the query is running perfectly find. When i run it in the Ipython notebook, it does do so. Just wondering whether there is a command to disable legacy sql from ipython notebook. Any help would be appreciated.

I tried with the below code but it does not get through.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT A.Id, Latitude, Longitude
FROM
   Data AS A
JOIN
   T12 AS B
ON
   A.StartTime <= B.DateTime
   AND A.StopTime >= B.DateTime
   AND A.HardwareId = B.HardwareId
WHERE
   (A._PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2016-11-24')
     AND TIMESTAMP('2016-11-24'))
     AND A.Id = 331
```

Comment: have you tried `#standardSQL` ? see more in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant: I tried with #standardSQL in IPython notebook but it does not go through.